# Trading Engine running on RHEL 5.x

Tags: linux, networking, performance, memory, central-processing-unit

Before asking question quick background about myself working at one of trading company this is my 1st job as sysadmin I have finish my RHCE no experience how production server work.

In our company there are many customize hardware right now which I don't know because I don't access to our data center so I don't know which is company has manufacture them I am sure they are not HP/DELL/IBM hardware. Neither they are (SUN) Oracle.

Reasons I am asking this question at this forum, While my study I have lot of reference and learning from the same **BIG THANK YOU FOR THE SAME**.

Last week we had issues at our trading RHEL server for latency, which application team has put blame on OS team.

But looking at sosreport from server can find any thing from OS part & Network & Storage team said they did not found any error on they side as well.

Do any one have any script which can take record application having how many connection what is application side going on at the same time what is Memory in use how much is use and free.

What is CPU and I/O Network ? at that time. Basically I want to do system profile.

They all are very senior guys out in my office but no one is help to get all above thing.

Back of my mind I have few idea is running SAR/IOSTAT/VMSTAT/HTOP/PS/ATOP/STRACE/PERF/TOP/SLABTOP all these if are one script it will be really nice.

```
Buffering and Caching
Swap
Runqueue process states
Interrupt count
I/O Hardware
CPU specifics
Memory architecture
VM garbage collection algorithms
```

I know is it all above help is **Black Art of Linux Performance Tuning**

**Thank you all @Serverfault salute **TECHGURU****

Answer (score 6):

You are in over your head... Step back and insist that a senior resource help you. **Money** is on the line. You are *setting yourself up for failure* by not asking for help at the right time... This is clearly not your problem to solve (alone).

---

In general, you should know how to obtain all of that information. You can see most of it via `top`, `cat /proc/interrupts`, `cpuinfo`, `dmidecode` and `ethtool`. For troubleshooting real trading application issues, I'd suspect you'll need a good amount of Wireshark analysis or will want to lean on existing monitoring. You will need to discuss application specifics with your development team.

Comment: GURU, Sure this is not my alone issues at my work place. I am agree with you guys. Getting understand with our application team. Above question was if any script is there with any one which I can use for getting data from these server.

Comment: @user199331 Please see if the organization has an *existing* monitoring infrastructure in place. There are many open-source monitoring tools that can give you a view of system health/vitals versus time.